# ¿Cómo crear una string con los valores de un diccionario mediante StringBuilder C# .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, string, foreach

Tengo un diccionario y quiero mostrar una **string** que contenga todos los valores del diccionario separados por espacios. Pruebo con el siguiente **foreach**:

```
   string dataString ="";
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in data)
    {
        dataString += entry.Value + " ";
    }
```

Esto funciona, pero **visual studio** me aconseja que use **StringBuilder** en su lugar. Sin embargo y a pesar de estar buscando la documentación de **StringBuilder** no consigo que haga la **string** de la misma manera.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Más información:
El diccionario data guarda datos de una persona, ejemplo:

```
name, Pepe
surname, Ruiz
location, España
```

La **string dataString** debería contener esto: "Pepe Ruiz España".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> visual studio me aconseja que use StringBuilder

Seguramente lo hace por un tema de eficiencia, en [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) las cadenas son constantes y concatenar varias cadenas como lo haces en el bucle supone crear-destruir una cadena en cada ciclo.

Para usar `StringBuilder`, intenta esto:

```
var dataStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in data)
{
    dataStringBuilder.AppendFormat("{0} ", entry.Value);
}
```

En el momento que necesites la concatenación final, simplemente llama `.ToString()`:

```
var concatenacion = dataStringBuilder.ToString();
```

Comment: Ha funcionado perfecto, gracias!